# Google maps behind a firewall

Tags: google, iptables

Is there any way or any script to permit only Google maps in my firewall and not the other Google apps like GMail or `accounts.google.com`?

The problem is that when I inspect the links, `maps.google.com` is redirected to `google.com/maps` and there is a possibility to accidentally allow GMail or other services if I dynamically permit `google.com`. I am using IPtables as firewall.

Any solution or idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

No you can't do that. You should be able to fix this using the API, but than u have to build the application somewhere on the other side :)